# why is a wget to http://graph.facebook.com resolving to my server's IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, wget, host, nslookup

This makes absolutely no sense and I spent 3 hours trying to figure this out. Suddenly all my scripts connecting to Facebook stopped working, so I tried to do this:

```
root@s01 [~]# wget http://graph.facebook.com
--2015-11-18 15:27:47--  http://graph.facebook.com/
Resolving graph.facebook.com... MY.SERVERS.IP
Connecting to graph.facebook.com|MY.SERVERS.IP|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Cookie coming from graph.facebook.com attempted to set domain to graph.facebook.com
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html.2'

    [ <=>                                                                                                                   ] 85,752      --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-11-18 15:27:47 (397 MB/s) - `index.html.2' saved [85752]

root@s01 [~]#
```

Strangely, when I connect to graph.facebook.com, it shows my server's IP instead. And I also can't access it via lynx, I get the same problem.

When I do a `nslookup` however or a `host` I get the correct IP for the Facebook graph server. What is happening here?

```
root@s01 [~]# nslookup graph.facebook.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
graph.facebook.com  canonical name = api.facebook.com.
api.facebook.com    canonical name = star.c10r.facebook.com.
Name:   star.c10r.facebook.com
Address: 31.13.70.1

root@s01 [~]# host graph.facebook.com
graph.facebook.com is an alias for api.facebook.com.
api.facebook.com is an alias for star.c10r.facebook.com.
star.c10r.facebook.com has address 31.13.70.1
star.c10r.facebook.com has IPv6 address 2a03:2880:f00d:1:face:b00c:0:1
star.c10r.facebook.com mail is handled by 10 msgin.vvv.facebook.com.
root@s01 [~]#
```

Comment: You should include the contents of `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: `resolv.conf` only has the nameservers 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4 while `hosts` has 127.0.0.1 for localhost and localhost.localdomain and the server's IP entry.

Comment: 4.4.4.4 does not appear to be a DNS server.

Comment: Figured it out! Somehow the `nscd` daemon cached the local IP as Facebook's IP. Weird!